# unix shell command that make the virtual desktop spin

Tags: linux, shell, unix, virtual-desktop

I'm looking for a way to make my virtual desktop change without using keyboard shortcuts.
I explain: I want to do a java program that will change my current desktop to the desktop at the left for exemple, let's say by clicking on a button. I've done it using keyboard shortcuts sent by the java program, but i want it more universal (i mean, that can work for everyone). Hope I'm clear enough!
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you available workspace (virtual desktop) names:

```
wmctrl -d
```

then

```
wmctrl -s <workspace name>
```

will move to the workspace.

Take a look at here http://tomas.styblo.name/wmctrl/ to see what window managers are supported.

My previous answer was:

[xrandr](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Xorg_RandR_1.2#Using_xrandr_to_do_useful_things) is probably what you want. Take a look at this wikipedia page [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RandR) too.

I thought xrandr will work but couldn't figure out how. I hope someone will comment and give the definite answer whether xrandr will work or not.

Comment: Well it's not what i want but it's probably because i didn't explain well. xrandr rotates the displaying, i want to switch to another desktop that is on the same monitor, like when you use ctrl + alt + right arrow with compiz for exemple.